# View all times app was opened

Tags: macos, applications

On macOS in the Finder, one can see when an app was last opened.

But suppose I have just opened the app and want to know the open history of the whole day, or of the past two days. Is it possible to find that out? Also, can I find the total time this app was active in the past x days?

Given two answers suggest using apps for this, is it possible "just" by using the standard pre-installed apps from apple?

Answer (score 3):

There are multiple apps which allow you to track application usage.

- [Timing App](https://timingapp.com) Paid
- [Usage](https://www.cheatsheetapp.com/Usage/) Free
- [Time Sink](https://manytricks.com/timesink/) Paid

*I am not affiliated with any of these products in any way.*

Answer (score 0):

I would also recommend my app [Timing](https://timingapp.com) for this.
It runs in the background and tracks whenever you use an app. You can then see what you did at any given time in your day, including the application and even the document:

[image: Timing Screenshot]

And on the Details screen, you can list all the time when you were using a particular app:

[image: Timing Screenshot]
<sub>(source: [timingapp.com](https://timingapp.com/presskit2/images/12_today_details.png))</sub>

So I think [Timing](https://timingapp.com) would be perfect for your purposes. (It also has tons of more advanced features, such as rules and manual time tracking.)